Zonal statistics (area of pixels google earth engine) in vector polygon using integer raster
I am trying to calculate zonal statistics from a integer raster within a vector polygon calculating sum of pixels area in google earth engine. For this, I use this script.
// Visualization parameters for true color image
var imageVisParam = {
  "opacity": 1, // Opacity of the layer
  "bands": ["SR_B3", "SR_B2", "SR_B1"], // Bands used for RGB visualization (B3: Red, B2: Green, B1: Blue)
  "min": 0.032451176567622524, // Minimum value for visualization
  "max": 0.1483658816495508, // Maximum value for visualization
  "gamma": 0.99 // Gamma correction for visualization
};

// Define the region of interest (ROI)


// Visualization parameters for NDVI
var ndviVisParam = {
  "opacity": 1, // Opacity of the layer
  "bands": ["NDVI"], // NDVI band for visualization
  "min": 0.17642802779988578, // Minimum value for visualization
  "max": 0.6816389950556295, // Maximum value for visualization
  "palette": ["ff3e0d", "22c814"] // Color palette for NDVI (red to green)
};

// Load Landsat 5 surface reflectance image collection
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('1984-01-01', '2001-12-01') // Filter images by date range
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10)); // Filter images with less than 10% cloud cover

// Function to apply scaling factors to the images
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  // Apply scaling factors to optical bands (SR_B.)
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  // Apply scaling factors to the thermal band (ST_B6)
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  // Add scaled optical and thermal bands to the image
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

// Apply scaling factors to the entire dataset
dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);

// Calculate the median image from the dataset
var mediandata = dataset.median();

// Add the true color image layer to the map, clipped to the ROI
Map.addLayer(mediandata.clip(roi), imageVisParam, 'True Color (321)',false);

// Calculate NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index)
var ndvi2000 = mediandata.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename('NDVI');

// Add the NDVI layer to the map, clipped to the ROI
Map.addLayer(ndvi2000.clip(roi), ndviVisParam, 'NDVI',false);

// Reclassify the NDVI image
var remapValues = [0, 0.5]; // Values to be remapped
var newValues = [1, 2];     // Corresponding new values

var reclassifiedNDVI = ndvi2000.remap(remapValues, newValues);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Get the band names as a list
var bandNames = reclassifiedNDVI.bandNames();

// Print the band names
print('Band names:', bandNames);






//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



//var reclassifiedNDVI = ndvi2000.gt(0.5).multiply(1).add(ee.Image(1).subtract(ndvi2000.gt(0.5)));
//var reclassifiedNDVI = ndvi2000.gte(0.5).multiply(1).add(ndvi2000.lt(0.5));
// var reclassifiedNDVI = ndvi2000.where(ndvi2000.lte(0.5), (1)) // Reclassify pixels with NDVI <= 0.5 as 1
//                               .where(ndvi2000.gt(0.5),(2)); // Reclassify pixels with NDVI > 0.5 as 2


print('reclassifiedNDVI',reclassifiedNDVI);
// Add the reclassified NDVI layer to the map, clipped to the ROI
Map.addLayer(reclassifiedNDVI.clip(roi), {min: 1, max: 2, palette: ['red', 'green']}, 'Reclassified NDVI');
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
//Export classified Image in the drive
var exportParams = {
  image: reclassifiedNDVI.clip(roi), // Image to export (clipped to ROI)
  description: 'Reclassified_NDVI_2000', // Descriptive name for the exported file
  scale: 30, // Export resolution in meters per pixel
  region: roi.geometry(), // Export region (geometry of the ROI)
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF', // Desired output format (GeoTIFF is common)
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true // Optimize for cloud storage (optional)
  }
};

// Export the image to your Drive
Export.image.toDrive(exportParams);

// This will create a task in the Earth Engine Code Editor Tasks tab.
// Click "Run" next to the task to initiate the export.
// Once complete, you'll find the image in your Drive.
print('ndvi2000',ndvi2000);



// Select the 'cluster' band from the clustering result for further analysis.
var classified = reclassifiedNDVI.select('remapped');

// Define a function to calculate the area of each cluster class within a feature.
function calculateClassArea(feature) {
  // Calculate the area of each cluster class.
  var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({ groupField: 1, groupName: 'remapped' }),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e10
    });

  // Convert the area calculations to a list and format the numbers.
  var classAreaLists = ee.List(areas.get('groups')).map(function(item) {
    var areaDict = ee.Dictionary(item);
    return ee.List([ee.Number(areaDict.get('remapped')).format(), 
                    ee.Number(areaDict.get('sum')).divide(1e6)]);
  });

  // Return the feature with the calculated areas as properties.
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), ee.Dictionary(classAreaLists.flatten())
        .set('DISTRICT', feature.get('DISTRICT'))
        .set('phy_detail',feature.get('phy_detail')));
}

// Map the area calculation function over the AoI FeatureCollection.
var districtAreas = roi.map(calculateClassArea);

// Define the fields to be exported.
var outputFields = ['DISTRICT','phy_detail'].concat(ee.List.sequence(1, 2).getInfo());

// Export the results to Google Drive as a CSV file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: districtAreas,
  description: 'NDVI_Reclass_Table_2001',
  folder: 'yu',
  fileNamePrefix: 'NDVI_Reclass_Table_2001',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: outputFields
});

https://code.earthengine.google.com/358c4cffad2810d48b41f072d8661fce?noload=true
In this script a csv is exported in the drive. The CSV file has four column namely 'DISTRICT', 'phy_detail','1' and '2'. In first and second column the value is populated. But in column '1' and '2' no pixels area are populated. How can I do this? what is wrong in my script?

The script will not work because reclassifiedNDVI was wrong remaped. This has not any class (expected 1 and 2 classes).

Why it was wrong remaped? Because there are not pixels with exact values of 0 and 0.5. Which are the classes that you want to map in terms of NDVI?

Wrongly remapped? When I print 'reclassifiedNDVI', it shows the band name as 'remapped' with pixel values from 1 to 2, and the raster data is integer. NDVI values should be between -1 to +1. I need to reclassify -1 to 0.5 (value=1) as no or poor vegetation, and 0.5 to +1 (value=2) as healthy vegetation. I did this as we traditionally do in QGIS or ArcGIS. Is reclassify different from remap? I want the script to export a CSV file with pixel area data. Here's the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd715db9233f39e0080ea042fcd3b010?noload=true. I think I'm missing something. pls, HELP.
